# v-app-bar component bug since update my dependencies

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-navigation-drawer

I'm new here.

I use the vueJS and vuetify framework for almost 1 year and the v-app-bar component bug since I updated all my dependencies.

My version of vue js : **2.6.11**
My version of vuetify before the bug : **2.2.3**

I took screenshots and modified them with paint. I highlighted the divs with a black fill and yellow border.

As shown in the following picture :

- I have an app-bar upstairs,
- a navigation-drawer under the app bar on the left side of the screen
- a v-content under the app bar in the middle

[picture before bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3uhK.png)

So far, so good. Yesterday I updated my dependencies (which I will do more often now). Below is the update:

[picture maj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4nZA.png)

My version of vuetify with the bug : **2.2.18**

Then by relaunching the application, my bug appears.

- The app bar is still on top - OK
- The navigation-drawer does not take into account the app bar and is placed behind it and in top 0 - KO
- The v-content has the same behaviour as the navigation-drawer - KO

All divs below the app-bar do not calculate the app-bar. But be careful, the weird thing is that this bug disappears when I refresh the page.

Look at the following image that shows the bug:

[picture now bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgznj.png)

To better understand I have highlighted the divs above the app bar in the following image:

[picture better now bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUHQ1.png)

What has changed in "vuetify" to have creating this bug?

I've tried to improve my architecture but I always find this bug.

**EDIT**

I found the version of vuetify when the bug appears : **2.2.5**

**FIXED**

The problem was due to my architecture. Thanks to the community for the help.

Comment: Is reverting to older version an option?

Comment: I think I do. I haven't tried. But my goal is to move forward with the versions, not stagnate.

Comment: please try and downgrade the value of the version of the vuetify in package.json.
but first, delete the node_modules folder. then run the comment $ npm install

Comment: Did you set any custom style to app-bar or drawer? just delete them and try again.